# Performace impact of using setStatsSampleRate/topology.stats.sample.rate

Tags: apache-storm

What is the performance impact of setting topology.stats.sample.rate: 1.0 in yaml?

How this works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`topology.stats.sample.rate` configures the rate at which a Storm topology statistics would be calculated.

Default value in [defaults.yaml](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/conf/defaults.yaml#L136) is `0.05`. This means only five out of 100 events are taken into account.
The value of `1` means each tuple's statistics is going to be calculated.

Is this going to decrease performance? Most likely many will say yes but since each environment is different, I would say it is better to measure it yourself. Increase and decrease the value and measure the throughput of your topology.

Comment: thanks it helped me alot but how can i measure it ? i'm new to this trying to measure of performance of my topology to compare it with another topology i mean how can i do that ?